# Snakemake: os.listdir() lists files that aren't there

Tags: python, conda, snakemake

Edit:

I started by calling `conda activate snakemake`

---

My Snakefile contains the following:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
 input: expand("{root_dir}/{geoid}/*.CEL", root_dir = config['root_dir'], geoid = config['geoid'])

rule getCelFiles:
 output: "{root_dir}/{geoid}/*.CEL"
 run:
  if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(wildcards.root_dir,wildcards.geoid)) :
   shell("Rscript scripts/getCELFiles.R {wildcards.geoid} "
         "cd {wildcards.geoid} && tar -xvf * && rm *.tar && gunzip *")
  else :
   print(os.listdir())
   print("getcwd:", os.getcwd())
   print(os.path.exists(os.path.join(wildcards.root_dir,wildcards.geoid)))
   print(os.path.join(wildcards.root_dir,wildcards.geoid))
```

When I run `ls` in the current directory, I get the following output:

```
config.yaml  old  README.txt  scripts  Snakefile
```

But the output of the `else` condition returns the following:

```
os.listdir(): 
['.snakemake', 'Snakefile', 'README.txt', 'scripts', '.DS_Store', 'old', 'GSE4290', 'config.yaml']

getcwd: 
/home/rebecca/workflows/exploring_tools/affymetrix_preprocess/snakemake # current working directory 

os.path.exists: True

os.path.join: 
/home/rebecca/workflows/exploring_tools/affymetrix_preprocess/snakemake/GSE4290 # directory that is being checked for
```

It seems there are files/folders there, namely `GSE4290`, that aren't "actually" there. I'm wondering if snakemake is running the `run` directive in some "parallel" environment? Basically, I'm not sure how to get ride of the `GSE4290` folder so that the code runs as expected (i.e. running the block with the Rscript commmand, etc.).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using `ls -a` and see all the directory file present in that directory

Comment: Are you sure that `output: "{root_dir}/{geoid}/*.CEL"` does not create the directory? because it looks like it does

Comment: @sahasrara62: I tried that, got the following output: ".  ..  config.yaml  .DS_Store  old  README.txt  scripts  Snakefile  .snakemake"

Comment: @DeepSpace Shouldn't that directory be produced after the "run" directive? I.e. When the Rscript is called, the output has not been produced yet. Furthermore, wouldn't that directory be there after the process is run if that were true? I guess this is testing my understanding of snakemake.

Comment: @DeepSpace Update: you are correct, the directory appears to be created at the start of the workflow, and thus exists while the workflow runs, even if it fails. Thanks!